# how to download (with out install) package from github

Tags: r, devtools

Is there anyway to download the zipped package from github and not have it installed?

For example running:

```
devtools::install_github("tidyverse/tidyr")
```

downloads and installs at once. Is there anything equivalent to

```
download.packages("tidyr", destdir = "path")
```

For github packages?

Comment: does this need to be from within R? why not just download the repo from github?

Comment: Like you just want an R function to do a `get clone` for you? Because there is no zipped package in the repo. That needs to be built. Or you want a function that downloads and builds but doesn't install? If you just want the zipped packages, it's easier to get the official released from CRAN rather than github. Or are you specifically trying to get development versions of the packages?

Comment: There are some packages in github that are not available on cran. Yes a function that downloads, and builds but doesn't install would exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to download a GitHub repository (in this case `tidyr` package) you can use `download.file` and copy the link in the GitHub "Clone or download" button by right click in it.

```
download.file(url = "https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyr/archive/master.zip",
              destfile = "tidyr.zip")
```

And if you want a function to do it, one possible solution could be (it will download on current working directory):

```
download_git <- function(repo_name, repo_url, install = FALSE){

   url_git <- paste0(file.path(repo, "archive", "master"), ".zip")
   download.file(url = url_git,
                 destfile = paste0(repo_name, "-master.zip"))

   if(install) {

      unzip(zipfile = paste0(repo_name, "-master.zip"))

      devtools::install(paste0(repo_name,"-master"))    
   }
}
```

and you here's an example with how to use it (with installing option):

```
download_git(repo_name = "tidyr", 
             repo_url = "https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyr", 
             install = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you may use:

```
repo <- "tidyverse/tidyr"
download.file(
  url = paste0("https://api.github.com/repos/", repo, "/tarball/master"), 
  destfile = "~/tidyr.tar.gz"
)
```

If you want to do it via a package, you could use `remotes`:

```
x <- list(host = "api.github.com", repo = "tidyr", username = "tidyverse", ref = "master")
tmpFile <- remotes:::remote_download.github_remote(x)
file.rename(tmpFile, "~/tidyr.tar.gz")
```

Which will effectively be equivalent to the above. Note the `remote_download.github_remote` function is not exported, so not the "official" way of using it.